# Adding multiple json data to panda dataframes

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am using a api to get 3 json data and I would like to add those datas to 1 panda dataframes

This is my code
I am passing in books which contains the book id as x and those 3 id returns me 3 different json objects with all the book information.

```
for x in books:
newDF = pd.DataFrame()
bookinfo = requests.get( http://books.com/?x})
    books = bookinfo.json() 
    print(books)
```

This is the 3 arrays I get after printing books,

```
{  
   u'bookInfo':[  
      {  
         u'book_created':u'2017-05-31',
         u'book_rating':3,
         u'book_sold':0
      },
      {  
         u'book_created':u'2017-05-31',
         u'book_rating':2,
         u'book_sold':1
      },
   ],
   u'book_reading_speed':u'4.29',
   u'book_sale_date':u'2017-05-31'
}
{  
   u'bookInfo':[  
      {  
         u'book_created':u'2017-05-31',
         u'book_rating':3,
         u'book_sold':0
      },
      {  
         u'book_created':u'2017-05-31',
         u'book_rating':2,
         u'book_sold':1
      },
   ],
   u'book_reading_speed':u'4.29',
   u'book_sale_date':u'2017-05-31'
}
{  
   u'bookInfo':[  
      {  
         u'book_created':u'2017-05-31',
         u'book_rating':3,
         u'book_sold':0
      },
      {  
         u'book_created':u'2017-05-31',
         u'book_rating':2,
         u'book_sold':1
      },
   ],
   u'book_reading_speed':u'4.29',
   u'book_sale_date':u'2017-05-31'
}
```

What I would like to do is only take `u'bookInfo` from the three arrays and make them into 1 dataframe

Comment: Could you provide expected output as well?

Answer (score 4):

IIUC:

```
pd.concat(
    pd.DataFrame([requests.get( http://books.com/?x}).json() for x in books]),
    ignore_index=True)
```

Alternatively you can collect JSON responses into a list and do the following:

```
In [30]: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x['bookInfo']) for x in d], ignore_index=True)
Out[30]:
  book_created  book_rating  book_sold
0   2017-05-31            3          0
1   2017-05-31            2          1
2   2017-05-31            3          0
3   2017-05-31            2          1
4   2017-05-31            3          0
5   2017-05-31            2          1
```

or

```
In [25]: pd.DataFrame([y for x in d for y in x['bookInfo']])
Out[25]:
  book_created  book_rating  book_sold
0   2017-05-31            3          0
1   2017-05-31            2          1
2   2017-05-31            3          0
3   2017-05-31            2          1
4   2017-05-31            3          0
5   2017-05-31            2          1
```

where `d` is a list of dicts, you've posted:

```
In [20]: d
Out[20]:
[{'bookInfo': [{'book_created': '2017-05-31',
    'book_rating': 3,
    'book_sold': 0},
   {'book_created': '2017-05-31', 'book_rating': 2, 'book_sold': 1}],
  'book_reading_speed': '4.29',
  'book_sale_date': '2017-05-31'},
 {'bookInfo': [{'book_created': '2017-05-31',
    'book_rating': 3,
    'book_sold': 0},
   {'book_created': '2017-05-31', 'book_rating': 2, 'book_sold': 1}],
  'book_reading_speed': '4.29',
  'book_sale_date': '2017-05-31'},
 {'bookInfo': [{'book_created': '2017-05-31',
    'book_rating': 3,
    'book_sold': 0},
   {'book_created': '2017-05-31', 'book_rating': 2, 'book_sold': 1}],
  'book_reading_speed': '4.29',
  'book_sale_date': '2017-05-31'}]
```

Comment: I am getting a type error with the first piece of code
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"