# Writing CSV from JSON returned from API

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am trying to write a CSV file from JSON returned from an API call.

I am using pandas, json and requests libraries.

```
response = requests.get("valid_api_call")
```

My response.json() looks like this:

```
"request": {
        "Target": "Affiliate_Report",
        "Format": "json",
        "Service": "service",
        "Version": "2",
        "api_key": "key",
        "Method": "getStats",
        "fields": [
            "Stat.offer_id",
            "Stat.offer_file_id",
            "Stat.hour",
            "Stat.date",
            "Stat.affiliate_info5",
            "Stat.affiliate_info4",
            "Stat.affiliate_info3",
            "Stat.affiliate_info1",
            "Offer.name"
        ],
        "limit": "10",
        "data_start": "2019-11-11",
        "data_end": "2019-11-18"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 1,
        "httpStatus": 200,
        "data": {
            "page": 1,
            "current": 10,
            "count": 23500,
            "pageCount": 2350,
            "data": [
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "18",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-11",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "1",
                        "affiliate_info1": "Other (unique values)"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "Special"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "18",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-11",
                        "affiliate_info5": "popup",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "6",
                        "affiliate_info1": "Other (unique values)"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "Special"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "18",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-11",
                        "affiliate_info5": "popup",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "1",
                        "affiliate_info1": "Other (unique values)"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "Special"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "18",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-11",
                        "affiliate_info5": "popup",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "1",
                        "affiliate_info1": "Other (unique values)"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "Special"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "18",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-11",
                        "affiliate_info5": "popup",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "6",
                        "affiliate_info1": "Other (unique values)"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "Special"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "18",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-11",
                        "affiliate_info5": "popup",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "6",
                        "affiliate_info1": "Other (unique values)"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "Special"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "18",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-11",
                        "affiliate_info5": "popup_below_2nd",
                        "affiliate_info4": "Other (unique values)",
                        "affiliate_info3": "1",
                        "affiliate_info1": "Other (unique values)"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "Special"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "18",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-11",
                        "affiliate_info5": "popup_below_2nd",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "1",
                        "affiliate_info1": "Other (unique values)"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "Special"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "18",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-11",
                        "affiliate_info5": "popup_below_2nd",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "6",
                        "affiliate_info1": "Other (unique values)"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "Special"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "18",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-11",
                        "affiliate_info5": "popup_below_2nd",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "6",
                        "affiliate_info1": "Other (unique values)"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "Special"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "dbSource": "branddb"
        },
        "errors": [],
        "errorMessage": null
    }
}
```

I am trying to write the output to a CSV file where the columns would be the field :

```
Stat.offer_id,
Stat.offer_file_id,
Stat.hour,
Stat.date,
Stat.affiliate_info5,
Stat.affiliate_info4,
Stat.affiliate_info3,
Stat.affiliate_info1,
Offer.name
```

I haven't worked with JSON that much, not sure how would I iterate the file and write ite to CSV with python. The way I am going to write the file  will probably look like this:

```
f = csv.writer(open(response,'w'))
f.writerow(keylist)
```

I do not think that csv.writer accepts response as a file which is the json returned by an API call.

I know there is a method with pandas to convert JSON to CSV

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

So my question would be what would be the smartest way of achieving CSV file as an output when the input is JSON returned by API call which may have pagination?

Thank you for the suggestions.

**EDIT:**

Second API response follows the same structure but throws an error - string indices must be integers.

```
{
    "request": {
        "Target": "Affiliate_Report",
        "Format": "json",
        "Service": "service",
        "Version": "2",
        "api_key": "key",
        "Method": "getStats",
        "fields": [
            "Stat.offer_id",
            "Stat.offer_file_id",
            "Stat.hour",
            "Stat.date",
            "Stat.affiliate_info5",
            "Stat.affiliate_info4",
            "Stat.affiliate_info3",
            "Stat.affiliate_info1",
            "Offer.name"
        ],
        "limit": "10",
        "data_start": "2019-11-20",
        "data_end": "2019-11-20"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 1,
        "httpStatus": 200,
        "data": {
            "page": 1,
            "current": 10,
            "count": 4037,
            "pageCount": 404,
            "data": [
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "20",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-20",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "info",
                        "affiliate_info1": "1"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "20",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-20",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "info",
                        "affiliate_info1": "1"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "20",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-20",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "info",
                        "affiliate_info1": "1"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "20",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-20",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "info",
                        "affiliate_info1": "1"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "20",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-20",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "info",
                        "affiliate_info1": "1"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "20",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-20",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "info",
                        "affiliate_info1": "1"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "20",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-20",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "info",
                        "affiliate_info1": "1"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "20",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-20",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "info",
                        "affiliate_info1": "1"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "20",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-20",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "info",
                        "affiliate_info1": "1"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Stat": {
                        "offer_id": "20",
                        "offer_file_id": "0",
                        "hour": "0",
                        "date": "2019-11-20",
                        "affiliate_info5": "editor_pick",
                        "affiliate_info4": "www.google.com",
                        "affiliate_info3": "info",
                        "affiliate_info1": "1"
                    },
                    "Offer": {
                        "name": "60"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "dbSource": "branddb"
        },
        "errors": [],
        "errorMessage": null
    }
}
```

Code used

```
response_2 = requests.get(JSON)
response_json_2 = response_2.json()
df_2 = pd.io.json.json_normalize(response_json_2['response']['data']['data'])
df_2.to_csv(f'{from_date} - 2.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Right now I am thinking if I should dump whole response into a JSON file and then read it and transform it to CSV or if there are more elegant solutions where I could simply write what API returns directly to a CSV.

Comment: Looks like you need something like `pd.io.json.json_normalize(response['response']['data']['data']).to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)`

Comment: It throws 'Response' object is not subscribtable. When I run your code after changing `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, try using [`pandas.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) like:

```
response_json = reponse.json()

# Or try this if it still doesn't work
# import json
# response_json = json.loads(response.json())

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(response_json['response']['data']['data'])
```

Should return the `DataFrame`

```
  Stat.offer_id Stat.offer_file_id Stat.hour   Stat.date Stat.affiliate_info5  \
0  18            0                  0         2019-11-11  editor_pick           
1  18            0                  0         2019-11-11  popup                 
2  18            0                  0         2019-11-11  popup                 
3  18            0                  0         2019-11-11  popup                 
4  18            0                  0         2019-11-11  popup                 
5  18            0                  0         2019-11-11  popup                 
6  18            0                  0         2019-11-11  popup_below_2nd       
7  18            0                  0         2019-11-11  popup_below_2nd       
8  18            0                  0         2019-11-11  popup_below_2nd       
9  18            0                  0         2019-11-11  popup_below_2nd       

    Stat.affiliate_info4 Stat.affiliate_info3   Stat.affiliate_info1  \
0  www.google.com         1                    Other (unique values)   
1  www.google.com         6                    Other (unique values)   
2  www.google.com         1                    Other (unique values)   
3  www.google.com         1                    Other (unique values)   
4  www.google.com         6                    Other (unique values)   
5  www.google.com         6                    Other (unique values)   
6  Other (unique values)  1                    Other (unique values)   
7  www.google.com         1                    Other (unique values)   
8  www.google.com         6                    Other (unique values)   
9  www.google.com         6                    Other (unique values)   

  Offer.name  
0  Special    
1  Special    
2  Special    
3  Special    
4  Special    
5  Special    
6  Special    
7  Special    
8  Special    
9  Special
```

Then [`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: I am getting 'Response' object is not subscriptable when running `df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(response['response']['data']['data'])`. I have imported `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize`. Is there another library which would fix the error?

Comment: apologies, my bad... you want to be using the "`json`" object as opposed to the "`response`" object. Try the updated answer?

Comment: Got it, thank you sir, it works. Would you mind explaining to me how would I go forward dealing with pagination in the API call? Let's say there is a limit of 100 in the call and there are 10 pages of the data which need to end up in the CSV file?

Comment: The proper question would be this: I would like to run the script every day and create CSV file for each day with the latest ( 24 hours ) of data. How would I ensure that all data is being taken having in mind that there would be pagination or limits in the API responses?

Comment: you could potentially append the converted `DataFrame` for each request to a list, then use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to join all of these to one `DataFrame` - for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728747/adding-multiple-json-data-to-panda-dataframes

Comment: Thank you for your help sir.

Comment: Hi again, I am reaching out to a different database where the response is the same JSON structure but I am getting the following error: `df_2= pd.io.json.json_normalize(response_json_2['response']['data']['data']) TypeError: string indices must be integers`. Any ideas what this could come from?

Comment: Check is `type(response_json_2)` - it looks like its a `str`...? either that or one of the nested arrays are strings. You could try `json.loads(response_json_2)`

Comment: The JSON i get from API is the same structure - added it to the original question.

Comment: The type is dict, same as the first one which works.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error from the 2nd example you've added. I can convert to DataFrame

Comment: When I use the JSON file it works, but when I am trying loading it from the API as before then the error happens, I have updated the second JSON response to have 10 objects in it, could you check if there is any visual difference which causes the error?

Comment: Added code snippet as well to the original question.

Comment: Was an error in my query, thank you for your help, Chris.